# Canvas ImageSource not showing image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, wpf-controls

Here is my xaml:

```
<StackPanel Height="333">
    <Canvas x:Name="imageCanvas"
        RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
        RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="image1"
                    Stretch="None"
                    AlignmentX="Left"
                    AlignmentY="Top">                                                     
            </ImageBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>                    
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas x:Name="overlayCanvas">
        <Rectangle Name="dummyRectangle" Width="1" Height="2" Fill="Transparent" />
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is my C# code behind:

```
void PlayImages()
{
    string testImageFolder = "C:\\TestImages";

    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(testImageFolder);//Assuming Test is your Folder
    FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.tif"); //Getting Text files       
    image1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\TestImages\\ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0001.tif"));

}
```

However, when the C# code above executed, nothing happened on UI. I am wondering where should I change to make the image show up? Thanks.

Comment: `C:\\Development2012\\ThorImage\\TIS_Development\\GUI\\Controls\\OverlayManager\\TestImages\\ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0001.tif` is image exists there?

Comment: An Uri with an absolute path `C:\...` and `UriKind.Relative` does not make *any* sense.

Comment: @Clemens So I removed the UriKind.Relative, also tried UriKind.Absolute, but image does not show either. Any idea how should I change it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the stack panel that causes the problem. I am not sure why, but if some of them are removed, then the image shows up. The xaml with some stack penal removed is like following:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <!--Controls:MenuControl/-->
                <Controls:ToggleButtonControl Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="43" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,-0.233"  />
            </StackPanel>

            <Canvas x:Name="imageCanvas"
                    RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                    RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Margin="0,52,0,0">
                    <Canvas.Background>
                <ImageBrush x:Name="image1"
                                Stretch="None"
                                AlignmentX="Left"
                                AlignmentY="Top"
                               ImageSource="{Binding Path=Bitmap, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                </ImageBrush>
                    </Canvas.Background>                    
                </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `imageCanvas` always has width and height zero, because you neither add any children, not set its `Width` or `Height` explicitly.

Change your XAML to use only one Canvas instead, and optionally (depending on the outer container and the children to be added) set its `Width` and `Height` properties:

```
<Canvas x:Name="overlayCanvas" Height="333" Width="500">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="image1" ... />
    </Canvas.Background>                    

    <Rectangle ... />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: No not working......no image showing up. I also change the Width="1" Height="2" to Width="100" Height="200" , still not working.....

Comment: You may check your image by assigning the `BitmapImage` to the `Source` property of an Image control.

Comment: I found an exception, something about metadata. I updated in the original thread, but cannot explain what that means. Any chance you can take a look? Thanks.

Comment: That only means that the `Metadata` property is not supported in BitmapImage. It doesn't matter.

Comment: OK. I should probably keep looking. Thanks.